# TeamSpeak 2 Library Question

Tags: 19.10, shared-library, teamspeak

I'm having a really hard time to get TS2 up and running on Ubuntu 19.10-64. I've got no problem at all when running it on antix-Debian, but when it comes to ubuntu I've found no possibile way to get it to work so far.
I'm stuck with an `undefined symbol: initPAnsiStrings` error I cannot resolve.
The program needs the libborqt-6.9-qt2 library shipped with the package which is linked to the libjpeg62 one which I have to install separately if not yet present in the system and so therefore I need to find the right one (I guess) to install in Ubuntu.

I use the same environmental variable path that works in the Debian machine before launching the binary

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/drive/TS2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

but when I move it into the Ubuntu machine, it throws that damn error.
There are loads and loads of writings out there about this, but I didn't find any help so far. The only difference I see between the two distributions is that in Debian a libjpeg62-turbo library is installed by default while in Ubuntu it's not and I can only choose between libjpeg62:i386 or libjpeg62 (32/64 bits), but none of them work. 
I really hope you guys can guide me to the right way to find what I'm missing here...

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, after hours of trying it came out in my case three libraries are mandatory for TS2 to run in Ubuntu

```
libice6:i386
libjpeg62:i386
libsm6:i386
```

the second one was known to me, different story for the other ones.

cheers